# fuzzy join with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I know there are questions with similar titles out there, but none of them really answers my question.
I have a data frame as below. The "index" column is actually timestamp. Column A is how many tones of materials have been dumped to a crusher. Column B is the crushing rate at each timestamp. What I want to know is when a load of material (column A) will be crushed based on crushing rate (column B).

There are three possible scenarios.

1. first load is crushed when second batch is loaded.
2. first load is crushed prior to second load
3. first load is not crushed when second load is added

I have tried to calculate the cumulative value of column A and B and used merge_asof to perform fuzzy join. But it doesn't work as expected as excessive crushing capacity is not stored. Only crushing rate after materials loaded should be considered.

```py
A = {'index':range(1,11),'A':[300,0,0,400,0,0,0,0,150,0]}
B = {'index':range(1,11),'B':[102,103,94,120,145,114,126,117,107,100]}
A = pd.DataFrame(data=A)
B = pd.DataFrame(data=B)
```

Here is the expected outcome:

```
IndexA  A   IndexB  B_accumulate 
1      300  4       419
4      400  8       502
9      150  10      207
```

B_accumulate  is running total of crushing rate(B), which is reset to 0 when a load of material is crushed (when B_accumlate>=A)

Comment: At index 4 the first load of 300 tonnes is crushed. At that point in time, there is still crushing capacity left, and the next load is already loaded. However, crushing of the next load only starts at the next point in time. Is this correct? Can we interpret this as "consecutive loads don't mix"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified the structures, using Series instead of DataFrame, and the indexes start at zero.
 cumsum() and searchsorted() are applied.

```
Load = pd.Series([300,0,0,400,50,0,0,0,150,0])  # aka 'A'
Rate = pd.Series([102,103,94,120,145,114,126,117,107,100])  # aka 'B'

# Storage for the result:
H=[]    # [ (indexLoad, Load, indexRate, excess) ... ]

# Find the 1st non 0 load:
load1_idx= len(Load)

for lix in range(len(Load)):
    a= Load[lix]
    if a!=0:
        csumser= Rate.cumsum()
        rix= csumser.searchsorted(a)
        excess= csumser[rix]-a
        H.append( (lix,a,rix,excess) )
        load1_idx=lix
        break

# Processing
for lix in range(load1_idx+1,len(Load)):

    a=Load[lix]
    if a==0:
        continue

    last_rix= H[-1][-2]
    csumser[last_rix:]= Rate[last_rix:]
    if lix==last_rix:
        csumser[lix]= H[-1][-1] # excess

    csumser[last_rix:]= csumser[last_rix:].cumsum()

    rix= csumser[last_rix:].searchsorted(a)
    rix+= last_rix
    excess= csumser[rix]-a
    H.append( (lix,a,rix,excess) )       

df= pd.DataFrame(H, columns=["indexLoad","Load","indexRate","rate_excess"])
print(df)

   indexLoad  Load  indexRate  rate_excess
0          0   300          3          119
1          3   400          6          104
2          4    50          6           76
3          8   150          7           93
```

Comment: Thanks kantal for your post. Your code almost answers my question. I only need to change your last_rix calculation to last_rix = H[-1][-2]+1. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very verbose solution which I hope is generalisable to your full data. I am sure you can simplify it.

```
C = A.join(B.set_index('index'), on='index')

C['A_filled'] = C['A'].replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')
C['cumul_load'] = C['A'].cumsum()
C['load_number'] = C.groupby('cumul_load').ngroup() + 1
C['B_accum'] = C.groupby('load_number')['B'].cumsum()
C['A_fully_crushed'] = C['B_accum'] > C['A_filled']
C['first_index_fully_crushed'] = C.groupby('load_number')['A_fully_crushed'].cumsum() == 1

indexA_ = C['index'][C['A'] > 0].tolist()
A_ = C['A'][C['A'] > 0].tolist()
indexB_ = C['index'][C['first_index_fully_crushed'] == True].tolist()
B_accumulate_ = C['B_accum'][C['first_index_fully_crushed'] == True].tolist()
result = pd.DataFrame({'indexA': indexA_, 'A': A_, 'indexB': indexB_, 'B_accumulate': B_accumulate_})
```

This yields

```
   indexA    A  indexB  B_accumulate
0       1  300       4           419
1       6  400       9           464
```

Comment: Hi @WolfgangK, Thanks for your solution. However, it doesn't really work in all cases. I should also mention that there are cases when first load hasn't been fully crushed but second load has been added already. For example, if I can change data frame A to A = {'index':range(1,11),'A':[300,0,0,400,0,0,0,0,0,0]}, your solution won't work.

Comment: @Cypress Thanks for checking out my post. Are there any more cases that my solution fails to cover? If so, consider adding those cases to your question.

Comment: I think there are three possible scenarios. 1) first load is crushed right before second load. 2) first load is crushed prior to second load. 3) first load is not crushed when second load is added. I will update the question.

Answer (score 1):

create the DF combined A & B:

```
A = {'index':range(1,11),'A':[300,0,400,0,0,0,0,0,100,0]}
B = {'index':range(1,11),'B':[102,103,94,120,145,114,126,117,107,87]}
df_A = pd.DataFrame(data=A)
df_B = pd.DataFrame(data=B)
df_com = pd.concat([df_A,df_B],axis=1).drop('index',axis=1)
```

create index:

```
indexA = list(df_com.A[df_com.A.ne(0)].index + 1)
indexB = np.array(indexA) - 2
indexB = np.append(indexB[1:],(len(df_com)-1))
```

replace 0 with ffill() in col A:

```
df_com['A'] = df_com.A.replace(0,method='pad')
```

groupby and add index columns:

```
df_new =df_com.groupby("A",sort=False).apply(lambda x:x.B.shift(1).sum()).reset_index()
df_new['indexA'] = indexA
df_new['indexB'] = indexB
df_new
```

Comment: Hi Rean, Thanks for your post. However, your solution only works for the sample data provided. However, the actual data is much bigger than the sample and your method won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Possible approach. The problem is splitted into 2 parts - get actual amount of material (which cannot be negative) and analyze loads (groups of rows when there is any amount of material to crush during current time step).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def get_load(df):
    """ get loaded material minus crushed material """
    current_load = (df['A'] - df['B']).values
    if current_load[0] < 0:
        current_load[0] = 0
    for idx in range(1, len(current_load)):
        correct_value = current_load[idx - 1] + current_load[idx]
        if correct_value < 0:
            current_load[idx] = 0
        else:
            current_load[idx] = correct_value
    return current_load

def get_work_load_chunk_stat(df):
    """ get chunks when material actually crushing """
    if df['load'].sum() == 0:
        return
    ans = pd.DataFrame(
        {'indexA': [df.iloc[0, :]['indexA']],
         'total_load': [df['A'].sum()],
         'loads_qty': [df[df['A'] > 0]['A'].count()],
         'indexB': [df.iloc[-1, :]['indexB']],
         'total_work': [df['B'].sum()]})
    return ans

if __name__ == '__main__':

    A = {'indexA': range(22),
         'A': [0, 300, 0, 0, 0, 0, 400, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 300, 0, 0, 0, 0, 400, 0, 100, 0, 0]}
    B = {'indexB': range(22),
         'B': [99, 102, 103, 94, 120, 145, 114, 126, 117, 107, 87, 99, 102, 103, 94, 120, 145, 114, 126, 117, 107, 87]}

    data = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data=A), pd.DataFrame(data=B)], axis=1)
    data['load'] = get_load(data)
    data['load_check'] = np.where(data['load'] == 0, 1, 0)
    data['load_check'] = data['load_check'].shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()
    # print(data)

    result = (
        data
        .groupby('load_check')
        .apply(get_work_load_chunk_stat)
        .reset_index(drop=True))
    print(result)
```

Output:

```
   indexA  total_load  loads_qty  indexB  total_work
0       1         300          1       4         419
1       6         500          2      10         551
2      12         300          1      15         419
3      17         500          2      21         551
```

Comment: Hi Poolka, thanks for your reply. However, I have tried it with my original dataset and it seems your solution still doesn't address the 3rd scenario. For this scenario, your code will combine the first and second load, which is not what I want.